# Existe diferença entre o uso do underscore e o .this?

Tags: c#

Pelo que vi, usa-se underscore para variáveis internas da classe:

```
class Pessoa {
    private string _nome;

    public Pessoa(string nome){
        _nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Para esse caso, o uso do .this, seria dessa forma?

```
class Pessoa {
    private string nome;

    public Pessoa(string nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Se sim, exitem diferenças entre os dois usos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código está correto

```
class Pessoa {
private string nome;

public Pessoa(string nome){
    this.nome = nome;
}
}
```

o .this irá sempre referenciar a propriedade interna da classe.

**Respondendo sua dúvida quanto ao uso:**

A orientação original para o .NET era nunca usar sublinhados, a menos que fossem parte de uma variável de membro privado e, em seguida, apenas como um prefixo, por exemplo *customerId. Isso provavelmente foi herdado do MFC onde 'm*' era utilizado como prefixo para variáveis ​​de membros.

*A prática atual  é não usar underscores. A desambiguação entre variáveis ​​de membros privados e parâmetros com o mesmo nome deve ser feita usando "**This**". De fato, todas as referências a membros privados devem ser prefixadas com 'This'.*

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782084/naming-conventions-in-c-sharp-underscores

Comment: Coloca a referencia disso por favor, isso não foi você que disse! eu acabei de ler isso.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, corrigido.

Comment: Esta resposta está correta. a outra não está completamente errada, mas cria confusão e indica coisas que não são recomendadas.

Answer (score 1):

O this é apenas um ponteiro para a sua classe. Através dele você consegue ver uma listagem das propriedades e métodos disponíveis na mesma.

Para o caso acima, você consegue escrever o segundo exemplo sem a utilização do this. Apesar de você poder usá-lo, ele não é obrigatório no seu código.

Se deseja saber mais sobre este ponteiro, consulte este link: [Ponteiro this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/y0dddwwd.aspx)

Com relação ao uso de propriedades com underscore, geralmente é utilizado quando criamos uma propriedade como o exempo abaixo:

```
    private string _nome;

    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _nome; }
        set { _nome = value; }
    }
```

Neste exemplo você cria uma propriedade de acesso público e uma de acesso privado onde você não deseja expor o seu acesso. Por padrão, a propriedade privada se escreve com o underscore.

Este tipo de propriedade é chamado de propriedade completa e costuma-se utilizar quando se deseja executar algum código nas ações de get e set.

Se deseja saber mais sobre tipos de propriedades, consulte o link abaixo.

[Tipos de Propriedades em C#](http://www.randrade.net/2016/11/28/um-papo-mais-teorico-sobre-propriedades-no-c/)